# Multiple Data Center and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My scenario is as following: We are going to deploy multiple data centers, we want to store each site's data locally while being able to read/update one site's data from another site. Shortly we want to use MongoDB as DDBMS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MongoDBs replica and sharding sets are data center aware and have data center aware read and write tags as well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#tag-sets so this is perfectly legitimate.

#### Edit

A much better link about your subject is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-center-awareness/